# Warning: String literal converted to char* in initialization

Tags: c++

What will be the best solution if we need to resolve the warning :

The code looks like below :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     // There is a call to the function myfunc
      myfunc(char*, char*, char*, int, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*,
                        char*, char*, char*, char*, char*, char*,
                        char*, char*, int, int, int, int, int,
                        int, int, int, int, int, int, int,
                        int, int,int,int=9999,int=11,int=8888,char* ="",char* ="");

 return 0;
}


  Warning: String literal converted to char* in initialization.
```

Here the problem that I am facing is - I think with last two char * ="". Also, since some of the default arguments are specified in between , so it has become mandatory to specify last two char* with double quotes.
Please let me know how to get rid of the warning message.

Comment: You gotta be kidding. Right? You didn't actually write a 37 arguments function.

Comment: @Jefffrey : Trust me. This is how it is in real code.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg not in any real code I've ever worked in... even in C people learn to package things in `struct`s

Comment: It's just horrible.  struct it up.

Comment: @MartinJames: I understand. But, it's an old code...somewhere 1990's old code. This is how some programmer have done coding.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg No programmer I know of would write a function like this, with 37 arguments.   Doesn't matter if it's 1990, or even 1980.   Hopefully whoever programmed this is in another profession.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a string literal(which is const) as a non const parameter which could be modified in the function. This is dangerous as this is(usually) read only memory. The compiler warns you of that fact.

If strings need to be modified, either you remove the default parameters or you use `std::string` and define them like so:

```
std::string = std::string()
```

It seems you have a lot or function arguments though, maybe a `class` or `struct` could be beneficial here. Then implementing last 2 parameters with std::string will be almost trivial as you will need to refactor all code calling the function anyway.

**EDIT**

Let's say `myfunc` is defined like so(I removed some params ;)) and uses some internal function to only read and then possibly modify the last param.

```
void myfunc(char* first, std::string second = std::string())
{
    // read_only_function takes a const char*
    read_only_function(second.c_str());

    // modify_function takes a char*, it should probably take a length too 
    // or have some kind  of documented agreement on length.
    char temp[choose_your_size];
    modify_function(temp, ... and possibly buffer size);
    second.assign(temp, ...); // Pick the according overloads
}
```

**Of course, this is only if you don't have control over those internal function. If you have, I would also refactor them to take std::string in param for modification.**

Finally, keep in mind that `std::string` does not necessarily contain a null terminated string so take care when using `c_str`.

Comment: The last two char * 's will definately get modified in the function. Please suggest anything else.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg Then it doesn't make sense to default to a temporary.

Comment: @David Schwartz : You mean to say , instead of char * = "" , I should use std::string = "". But, then the other internal functions will need a change, which are using char*.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg If those internal function need to change the strings, they will need to change too. If not, you can pass them a `const char*` by calling string's `c_str` method.

Comment: @Eric Fortin: Can you please give example.

Comment: @ShubhraGarg Example of what ?

Comment: @Eric Fortin : using this c_str...

Comment: @ShubhraGarg Updated my answer with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Change the last two parameters to `const char *` or, better yet, `std::string`.

You can also have them default to `NULL` and code the function to handle that case as if it was passed an empty string.